# How to maintain relative positions/sizes of dynamically sized, stacked div's

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

[This page](https://logo-static.glitch.me/) centers and shrinks my logo to fit in the browser window. It uses a single PNG file and CSS flexbox with `max-width/max-height`. ([View code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/logo-static?path=style.css))

[This page](https://logo-animated.glitch.me/) animates the same logo. However, in order to limit the ripple effect to just the blue portion, some changes were needed ([view code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/logo-animated?path=style.css)):

- Logo split into two parts and stacked on top of each other (position:absolute).
- Hard-coded the size of the logo. (No longer sized based on size of browser window)

**I can't figure out two things:**

- How do I change the hard-coded sizes back to dynamic sizes based on the browser size? I also hard-coded the top and left, but if the two images are centered and scaled by the same ratio, they should line up properly without offsets.
- <strike>How do I vertically/horizontally center the logo, again? I think my previous flexbox CSS doesn't work because the elements have position:absolute.</strike> **Update:** I was able to get centering to work again, but this involved more hard-coded width/heights.

I think I can do this via JavaScript, but is a pure CSS/HTML solution possible? (I have a feeling centering *and* dynamically sizing elements with position:absolute might not be possible). If JavaScript is disabled, the solution should gracefully degrade (the two parts of the logo are correctly aligned; the logo fits inside browser window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/2rdjfwhb/1/

It is possible to do both with CSS, you just need another wrapper element around the "logo" class. This wrapper element can be positioned naturally inside of a flexbox. After that it's just about calculating the ratio you need for your logo image and the ripple canvas.

```
.parent {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    position: relative; /* Parent handles centering this guy now */
}

.logo-ligature {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; /* Positioned for z-index */
    pointer-events: none;
}

.logo-background {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.glitch.com/b2cea96d-c2a3-486e-90d5-f60a651a36e3%2Fle_square_light_noborder.png?1553791477453);
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center; /* Center the image */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.5%;
    left: 12.5%;
}
```

Comment: This almost works! I added `object-fit: contain` to `.logo-ligature`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for `.logo-background`. Any ideas about how to also get `.logo-background` to keep its square aspect ratio? (when container is very wide)

Comment: The extra parent div is not needed; just setting `.logo` `max-width` and `max-height` is enough. I forced the square aspect ratio on `.logo-background` by patching the Ripples init/updateSize algorithm. Accepting this answer because the percentage `top/bottom` helped me get to a final solution.

Comment: Ahhh my fault, I didn't think about keeping the aspect ratio. I'm glad you found a solution even without using the parent class!